# Deduce the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem from the Heine-Borel Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working through a proof of the above that goes something like

> If $I$ is a compact interval, suppose toward a contradiction that there exists an infinite real sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $I$ without a convergent subsequence. Then for every $x \in I$ there exists an $\epsilon_x$ such that $I_x = ( x - \epsilon_x, x + \epsilon_x )$ contains only finitely many $x_n$. It follows that $\cup_{x \in I} I_x \supset I$ is an open cover, without finite subcover. $\rightarrow \leftarrow$

I have trouble following this reasoning. Especially the part that says "It follows that $\cup_{x \in I} I_x \supset I$ is an open cover, without finite subcover". Why does it follow that there is no finite subcover? I don't see how the sequence previously defined implies anything about the covering of the interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there were a finite subcover, it contains only finitely many of the $x_n$, because each interval in the cover does so, so, that cover leaves out many of the $x_n$ thus it's not a cover.

Comment: but doesn't the open cover (that's not finite) also contain only finitely many $x_n$ because it's composed of the intervals $I_x$ that themselves only contain finitely many $x_n$?

Comment: @flapjackery Not necessarily. For example if the open cover is such that each interval contains one $x_n$ then it will contain an infinite number of the $x_n$, as long as there are infinite intervals in the cover.